# I can't turn ON bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have an HP Pavilion using UBUNTU 18.04 
When I open system settings under hardware I click on the Bluetooth icon 
a window opens but won't turn ON. How do you set the on/off features for bluetooth settings?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: This helped me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036195/bluetooth-doesnt-work-after-resuming-from-sleep-ubuntu-18-04-lts