# Bluetooth doesn't work after resuming from sleep, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth, 18.04, bug-reporting

Bluetooth earphones work fine until sleep. After resuming from sleep however, they appear to connect for a brief moment before disconnecting. On blueman, the error given is Resource temporarily unavailable. This issue arose only after updating to 18.04 LTS.

Here's the terminal output for lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1bcf:0002 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b477 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21f1 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable Bumble Bee
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I have the same issue with JBL Go speaker and a fresh install of 18.04. Nothing like restarting `bluetooth.service` or removing `btusb` module and reinserting it again worked. I had to *reboot*.

Comment: I have the same problem, whenever resuming from sleep there is a chance ubuntu acts like there is no bluetooth at all (hence why restarting the service doesn't work).  Sleeping and resuming again solves it sometimes.

Comment: @K7AAY for some reason hibernate doesn't work at all, so I can't verify that.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Comment: Same problem here.  I have to reboot to get the speakers working again.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### update bluez to >=5.28.2

18.04 ships with a buggy bluez package for now; newer version is available from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~bluetooth/+archive/ubuntu/bluez:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt install bluez
```

---

#### workaround for buggy Bluetooth applet (Unity specific?)

This is probably the issue @solstice mentioned - BT menu applet doesn't let me enable Bluetooth after resuming from sleep. No matter if the toggle switch is off or on, the BT icon is disabled, and rfkill output doesn't change:

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
12: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

You can toggle BT manually by running (substitute your own ID):

```
rfkill block 12
rfkill unblock 12
```

and BT applet should pick it up correctly now. At this point, you should be able to connect to your devices. For now I've hacked it together using a script that does this automatically after resume:

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system-sleep/bt
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  post)
    sleep 5
    rfkill block `rfkill list | grep hci | cut -d: -f1`
    sleep 1
    rfkill unblock `rfkill list | grep hci | cut -d: -f1`
    ;;
esac
```

The ID number next to hci0 in rfkill list output seems to increment after every suspend/resume. Disabling/enabling BT using the BT menu should change the output ('soft blocked: yes' for BT disabled via menu), but it doesn't. My guess is that the applet remembers the wrong device ID and is thus trying to enable a device that no longer exists.

Comment: Just updating the bluez package did it for me, thank you!

Comment: Same updating bluez worked like a charm!

Comment: Update: It only worked for 1 sleep cycle. However, after multiple, I am back to the same problem.

Comment: Unless the bug has already been fixed by an update, the bluez update worked for me.

Comment: Using the blueman applet (`sudo apt install blueman`) and updated bluez (from ppa) is working well for me.

Comment: BTW, just going to bluez >= 5.28.2 isn't enough.  I was experiencing the issue with bluez 5.48 from Ubuntu's Bionic repo.  5.50 from the PPA seems to fix the issue.

Comment: this not only solves the resume problem, but it seems to stop connection dropouts for the Apple Magic Trackpad. I wonder why this is not in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can confirm that this fix also fixed my bluetooth disconnection on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Sadly on focal/20.04: `The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`. On launchpad git it doesn't exist a ppa-cosmic branch as said in the home. There is a focal, though.

Answer (score 17):

For me this problem can be resolved by running

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

after waking from sleep

Comment: Running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, this is what worked for me :)

Comment: ah, worked for me on Ubuntu 21.04 !

Answer (score 16):

I run 19.04 and have this issue. I have a BT mouse so it really is annoying.

To enhanced @hinxnz answer:

Open an new file:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/bt
```

Paste in this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  post)
    modprobe -r btusb
    sleep 1
    service bluetooth restart
    sleep 1
    modprobe btusb
    ;;
esac
```

An finally make it executable

```
chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/bt
```

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: The `modprobe -r btusb` (and re-enabling the module afterward) worked for me on Opensuse Tumbleweed 2023 too.

Answer (score 3):

Try in a terminal (no root needed)

```
btnum=`rfkill list|grep hci0| cut -f 1 -d ':'`
rfkill block $btnum
rfkill unblock $btnum
```

This might be related to a bug in gnome-control-center. Not sure. I have found this to work around that said bug and may be yours too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix the issue for me. Thanks for sharing though!

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did to get it working on 18.04 LTS

Updated bluetooth:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt install bluez
```

Create new file:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/bt
```

Write and save:

```
#!/bin/sh

modprobe -r btusb
sleep 1
service bluetooth restart
sleep 1
modprobe btusb
```

Changed permissions:

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/bt
```

Comment: Using chmod +x would be a safer solution if you just want to make this executable.  Doing this would allow any user on the system to run anything as root just by replacing the contents of this file.

Comment: after saving this script, my Dell XPS (18.04lts) won't go to sleep. it looks like it goes to sleep and 2sec later wakes up, and that's it.

Comment: Don't chmod 777, ever. Unless you know exactly what you are doing. You should wrap that script with `case $1 in post)` so it only run after wakeup. Also sudo is not needed in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/602313/278074), for pulseaudio & Ubuntu 18

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Answer (score 0):

For me changing bluetooth adapter to another USB port helped. A moment after waking up I heard that headset disconnect. My front panel USB has  short power off time during the waking up and it disconnect and remove devices.

Answer (score -1):

The solution of upgrading to a newer version of bluez solved another problem for me of bluetooth connections disconnecting seconds after connecting, as described here: [Ubuntu 18.04: Bluetooth device disconnects right after connect on Lenovo P50](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037370/ubuntu-18-04-bluetooth-device-disconnects-right-after-connect-on-lenovo-p50)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, `laptop-mode-tools` was the culprit:

> $ sudo apt remove laptop-mode-tools

Comment: Please do not post the *same answer* to many posts.  Instead, if the posts are similar enough to each other, flag the other posts as duplicates of one of the other ones.  Simply reposting the same answer to multiple questions is very noisy.