# Can't turn on bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth

My Bluetooth suddenly stopped working in the middle of usage and I couldn't turn it on until I restarted my machine.

**Bluetooth in the settings:**

[image: Bluetooth in the settings]

**Bluetooth in the top bar:**

[image: Bluetooth in the top bar]

Below is the output of my `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

I tried unblocking it from the command line using `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` and reinstalling the `bluez` package by running `sudo apt install --reinstall bluez`, but both methods did not work.

I just upgraded my machine to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 and thought this problem would go away, but in fact it persists. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same exact problem this morning. What was your solution?

Comment: @Jeff never found a solution. I tried googling and asking in the forum, but none helped

Comment: Try upgrading bluez as descibed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036195/bluetooth-doesnt-work-after-resuming-from-sleep-ubuntu-18-04-lts

Comment: Same issue here, no solutions so far

Comment: Same problem here. Upgrading bluez does not help

Comment: We need further information. Please share the output of this first `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was

1. Reboot
2. Turn off the bluetooth in the BIOS
3. Exit
4. Get into the BIOS again and turn it on...

This is super tedious and I'm still looking for a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me was to reload the `btusb` module, like this:

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

I did this on Debian 10, Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 21.04, … It never ends.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and kept trying different solutions, until i saw a StackOverflow post stating to just:

> Shutdown and ​Boot again

This fixed the problem with me.