# Bluetooth adapter missing after every shut down

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth

I have installed the [bluetooth driver for Ralink RT3290](https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms) and it works perfectly.

But every time I start my machine up again, blueman complains that the bluetooth adapter is missing. `rfkill` doesn't return anything for bluetooth and restarting the service doesn't help. I have to remove the module using `rmmod` and install it again using `modprobe` every time.

I have also restarted my machine with the power plug on following the [answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1214211/1148446) but it didn't help.

How can I make the bluetooth adapter installation permanent?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David I am on Ubuntu 20

Comment: There is no version 20. There is a 20.04 and a 20.10

Comment: @David Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Sorry, didn't think there was a difference.