# Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize Internal Bluetooth after suspend

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, suspend

I have a ASUS with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have seen that my Bluetooth does not work after a suspend of my computer. The only solution that I have found is restart again the computer. I have tried the solution for this problem [Bluetooth does not work after resuming from sleep Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036195/bluetooth-doesnt-work-after-resuming-from-sleep-ubuntu-18-04-lts), but it does not work. I have already a greater version from bluez `5.53-0ubuntu3.1` that the one that has the problem. My problem is related to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313640/bluetooth-not-working-after-suspend), but none has response.

I really appreciate any help because I work remotely and I need to have all the time headsets.

Thank you for your time.

Terminal Output before suspend

```bsh
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:3010 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b483 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.770780] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.770816] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.770820] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.770822] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.770826] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.634896] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.634898] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.634901] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.691202] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.691210] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.691216] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Terminal Output after suspend

```bsh
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:3010 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b483 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.738454] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.738472] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.738475] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.738477] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.738479] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.483031] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.483032] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.483035] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.747496] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.747504] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.747510] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[10365.247046] Bluetooth: Can't get version to change to load ram patch err
[10365.247050] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I did few tests this afternoon on this subject, and suspects that ubuntu was not properly closing Bluetooth somehow.

Tried to modify : /etc/bluetooth/input.conf, uncommented:

IdleTimeout=5

UserspaceHD=true

And so far, tested with my JBL GO 3, whatever I do the JBL connects again.

Maybe it might need more testing, will try to let you know :)