# How can I force Bluetooth Manager to restart after suspend?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, suspend, power-management, blueman

I am running 20.04.3 LTS. When I start my machine, Bluetooth Manager starts as expected and I can connect to Bluetooth devices can connect. In my power settings I have "Bluetooth can be turned off to save power" enabled.

If I leave my machine to suspend, Bluetooth Manager disappears, I cannot restart it, and I can no longer connect any Bluetooth devices. How can I force it to restart without having to reboot my machine? (Or prevent the problem in the first place?)

### Normal status

Before anything goes wrong, the output of `/etc/init.d/bluetooth status` is as follows:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-02-15 11:20:46 GMT; 1h 18min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1857 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18495)
     Memory: 2.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1857 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 15 11:20:46 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: audio-avrcp-target: Protocol not supported (93)
Feb 15 11:20:47 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.42 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 15 11:20:47 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.42 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 15 11:20:50 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: L2CAP server failed for Message Notification: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Feb 15 11:20:50 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: L2CAP server failed for Message Access: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Feb 15 11:20:50 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: L2CAP server failed for Phone Book Access: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Feb 15 11:20:50 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: L2CAP server failed for File Transfer: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Feb 15 11:20:50 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: L2CAP server failed for Object Push: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Feb 15 11:21:22 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: avrcp-controller profile connect failed for 00:08:8A:FF:53:3D: Input/output error
Feb 15 11:21:22 lenovo bluetoothd[1857]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_08_8A_FF_53_3D/sep1/fd0: fd(38) ready
```

### Normal status II

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep blue
blueman-mechanism.service                      disabled        enabled      
bluetooth.service                              enabled         enabled      
dbus-org.bluez.service                         enabled         enabled      
bluetooth.target                               static          enabled
```

### What I have tried

#### Restarting service

From [Bluetooth doesn't work after resuming from sleep, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036195)

```bsh
modprobe -r btusb
sleep 1
service bluetooth restart
sleep 1
modprobe btusb
```

Result: No change.

#### Check device status

Still active and running (!?)

```
$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-02-17 09:30:24 GMT; 7h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1859 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18495)
     Memory: 2.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1859 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 17 14:12:48 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 17 14:13:33 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: avrcp-controller profile connect failed for 00:08:8A:FF:53:3D: Input/output error
Feb 17 14:13:33 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_08_8A_FF_53_3D/sep1/fd2: fd(37) ready
Feb 17 15:46:05 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: No reply to Start request
Feb 17 15:46:05 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 17 15:46:05 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: avrcp-controller profile connect failed for 00:08:8A:FF:53:3D: Input/output error
Feb 17 15:46:05 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_08_8A_FF_53_3D/sep1/fd3: fd(37) ready
Feb 17 16:16:46 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 17 16:16:46 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.41 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 17 16:16:46 lenovo bluetoothd[1859]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.41 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

#### Check device status II

```
$ lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 27c6:55a4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    6.728422] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin (v1.9)
[  131.924258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[  132.022131] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  132.022154] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  132.022159] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  132.022162] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  132.022166] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  132.147943] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.4 build 0 week 11 2017
[  132.148943] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[  132.148945] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[  132.148946] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[  132.148947] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[  132.148947] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[  132.148947] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[  132.152089] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-32-4.sfi
[  133.715425] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[  133.715942] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1527196 usecs
[  133.716026] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[  133.731078] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 14720 usecs
[  133.731693] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-32-4.ddc
[  133.734061] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[  133.736995] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 121 week 36 2020
[  133.796965] Bluetooth: hci0: MSFT filter_enable is already on
[  135.656768] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  135.656771] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  135.656778] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  136.784480] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  136.784487] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  136.784491] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  151.284331] audit: type=1107 audit(1645090240.283:147): pid=1864 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=3385 label="snap.bitwarden.bitwarden" peer_pid=1859 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 1612.134048] audit: type=1107 audit(1645091700.798:179): pid=1864 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=15716 label="snap.bitwarden.bitwarden" peer_pid=1859 peer_label="unconfined"
```

#### Check device status III

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep blue
blueman-mechanism.service                      enabled         enabled      
bluetooth.service                              enabled         enabled      
dbus-org.bluez.service                         enabled         enabled      
bluetooth.target                               static          enabled
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/68335639/236081

This *may* indicate that multiple conflicting services are inhibiting Bluetooth. (Still investigating. Note that `blueman-mechanism.service` is DISABLED in normal status.)

#### Start blueman-manager from the command line

```
$ blueman-manager
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting  
blueman-manager 12.42.28 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.  
blueman-manager 12.42.28 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

Result: Fails to start. Adapter not found.

#### Turning it off and on again

- In power settings, I tried turning "Bluetooth can be turned off" setting off and on again.
- A hit my keyboard button for "Airplane mode", setting it off and on again.

Result: In each case, Bluetooth Manager indicator pops up then disappears.

Comment: Is your Bluetooth radio on a USB or a PCI device? You may be able to power cycle *just* the Bluetooth transmitter depending on what it is and how it’s connected 

Comment: @matigo It's a PCI (builtin) device. Now that you mention it, I have an "airplane mode" button on the keyboard, I will try that next time. Thanks!

Comment: Post results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` after suspending

Comment: @Jeremy31 thanks for the tip, the results include an audit error from my bitwarden snap, but killing bitwarden then trying all the restart options doesn't seem to have made a difference -- is there anything I should be looking for in those results?